# Sending email notification to existing user Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send email to all existing admins once a user sends a request. I am using a Notifiable class to send emails but I am getting an error of :-

```
Call to a member function notify() on string
```

The code for me to notify all admins:-

```
$all_admins = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
                $query->where('admin', '1');
            })->paginate(100);

foreach($all_admins as $admin){
     if ($type == 1){
        $subject = $username.' made a lawyer request.';
        $message = "User: ". $user;
        $message2 = "Please handle the request in the admin portal under the request tab.";
     }

     $user = $admin->email;
     //$admin->email has a string of an email
     $user->notify(new EmailAdmin($subject, $message, $message2)); <--
     ***The above code is the code that is marked when laravel is returning the error to me.
}
```

Comment: You wrote it yourself. `$admin->email` is a *string*. The error says you're calling a function on a string. You're doing it wrong. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications says you're supposed to call `notify()` on a User model that has the trait.

Comment: Damn... I am really blur these days ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote it yourself. `$admin->email` is a string. The error says you're calling a function on a string. You're doing it wrong.

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) says you're supposed to call `notify()` on a User model that has the trait.

*(answered in the comments by @IGP)*